# PrimeFaces maxdate does not seem to be working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this piece of code:

```
<p:calendar id="dateofrenewal" 
    value="#{fishingShowView.selectedFishingLicense.dateOfRenewal}" 
    maxdate="#{fishingShowView.selectedFishingLicense.dateOfRenewal}" 
    navigator="true" showOn="button" readonlyInput="false" 
    locale="#{facesContext.viewRoot.locale}" required="true" />
```

I want the max date that the user can pick form this component to be equal to the dateOfRenewal that I am getting from my ManagedBean. The *value* attribute works fine but *maxdate* is not.

I am working with PrimeFaces version 6.2

Please help. Thanks in advance

EDIT: As I mention in the comment below I expect the restricted dates to be disabled as shown in the [Primefaces Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml) for the coresponding restricted dates. Currently all dates are available for the user to pick from. Sorry for not mentioning that in the original post.

Here is a sample of the back end code:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FishingShowView {
    private FishingLicense selectedFishingLicense;

    public FishingLicense getSelectedFishingLicense() {
        return selectedFishingLicense;
    }
}

@Entity
public class FishingLicense implements Serializable { 
    @Column(name = "XXX")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateOfRenewal;

    public Date getDateOfRenewal() {
        return dateOfRenewal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the source code of that managed bean building and returning the dateOfRenewal (or even better a minimal complete example source code). Describe what you expect to happen and what actually happens. "Does not work" is not that accurate. Nevertheless your issue might have to do with missing or incompatible date format patterns.

Comment: As shown in the PrimeFaces Showcase https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml I expect to see the restricted dates disabled. Now all the dates are allowed.

Comment: Play around with calendar pattern attribute and/or a dateConverter. Whatever the calendar gets for the maxdate attribute from your bean must be converted to a javascript date representation comparable on client side. The source code doing so is quite complex and heavily taking the pattern attribute into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your PrimeFaces reference, they use a mindate as well, you just need that in your code:

```
<p:calendar id="dateofrenewal" 
value="#{fishingShowView.selectedFishingLicense.dateOfRenewal}"
mindate="#{fishingShowView.selectedFishingLicense.minDateOfRenewal}" 
maxdate="#{fishingShowView.selectedFishingLicense.dateOfRenewal}" 
navigator="true" showOn="button" readonlyInput="false" 
locale="#{facesContext.viewRoot.locale}" required="true" />
```

Comment: So you mean maxdate does not work unless there also is a mindate? Which PF version did you encounter this?